# Perl sub returns a subroutine

Tags: perl, return, subroutine

I haven't used Perl for around 20 years, and this is confusing me. I've g******d for it, but I obviously haven't used a suitable search string because I haven't found anything relating to this...

Why would I want to do the following? I understand what it's doing, but the "why" escapes me. Why not just return 0 or 1 to begin with?

I'm working on some code where a sub uses "return sub"; here's a very truncated example e.g.

```
sub test1 {
  $a = shift @_;

  if ($a eq "cat") {
    return sub {
      print("cat test OK\n");
      return 0;
      }
  }
# default if "cat" wasn't the argument
  return sub {
    print("test for cat did not work\n");
    return 1;
    }
}

$c = test1("cat");
print ("received: $c\n");
print ("value is: ",&$c,"\n");

$c = test1("bat");
print ("received: $c\n");
print ("value is: ",&$c,"\n");
```

Comment: You ask us why code we know nothing about is written the way it is. How can we possibly answer that?

Comment: If you come from an OO background, then thinking of an anonymous sub as a small single-object method could be a useful mental exercise.  Binding in some values through a closure is a lot like instantiating an object with private data.

Comment: Ikegami - I know nothing about why it's written like that - that's why I asked the question (I don't even know if the original author is still with us, so I can't ask them...).

Comment: The problem isn't that you asked; the problem is that you didn't provide any information about the code you're asking about. You provided code completely unrelated to your question instead.

Comment: Sorry if you think it's unrelated - maybe I asked the question badly. The original code has a bunch of if else's, each of which returns a sub (each of which returns 0 or 1, when called). I edited it down to just one test, which returns a sub, and the default, which returns a sub. How is that unrelated? I don't want to get into an argument, I would just like to get an idea why i would want to do that rather than return a scalar from each test.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is no reason to return a sub. However, with a little tweak

```
sub test1 {
    my $animal = shift @_;

    if ($animal eq "cat"  || $animal eq "dog") {
        return sub {
            print("$animal test OK\n");
            return 0;
        };
    }

    # default if "cat" or "dog" wasn't the argument
    return sub {
        print("test for cat or dog did not work\n");
        return 1;
    };
}
```

We now have a closure around `$animal` this saves memory as the test for cat and dog share the same code. Note that this only works with my variables. Also note that $a and $b are slightly special to Perl, they are used in the block of code that you can pass to the sort function and bypass some of the checks on visibility so it's best to avoid them for anything except sort.

Comment: Bear with me while I get my head around this. This goes part way to answering my question, but I don't see the advantage in returning a sub that I'd have to call to get my "0" if I've got a cat, rather than just returning "0" in the first place. Thanks for the tip regarding $a and $b, it's not something that would have occurred to me (though in general I avoid one-character variable names).

Comment: Re "*I don't see the advantage in returning a sub that I'd have to call to get my "0"*", Are you claiming that the code you're asking about returns a sub that unconditionally returns zero?

Comment: Either a "0" or a "1". Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to search "perl closures".

There are many reasons that you'd want to return a code reference, but it's not something I can shortly answer in a StackOverflow question. Mark Jason Dominus's [Higher Order Perl](https://hop.perl.plover.com) is a good way to expand your mind, and we cover a little of that in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com).

I wrote [File::Find::Closures](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Closures) as a way to demonstrate this is class. Each subroutine in that module returns two code references—one for the callback to `File::Find` and the other as a way to access the results. The two share a common variable which nothing else can access.

Notice in your case, you aren't merely calling a subroutine to "get a zero". It's doing other things. Even in your simple example there's some output. Some behavior  is then deferred until you actually use the result for something.

Having said that, we have no chance of understanding why the programmer who wrote your particular code did it. One plausible guess was that the system was set up for more complex situations and you're looking at a trivial example that fits into that. Another plausible guess was that the programmer just learned that feature and fell in love with it then used it everywhere for a year. There's always a reason, but that doesn't mean there's always a good reason.

Comment: Okay, this is actually very helpful (but I have confused things a bit by including the "print"s, which don't exist in the original code, so _really_, all that comes out is either 0 or 1, depending on the particular if...else... route through the code. Mea culpa). My suspicion is that (because this kind of code is only in one shortish sub in ~12,000 lines of code) that the original programmer just thought it would be a good idea at the time... Many thanks for this, and thanks to JGNI for their suggestion that it probably isn't needed.